# Android Studio - finalizar actividad desde IntentService

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-service

tengo un activity que inicia un IntentService del cual verifica un codigo que le ingreso y si es correcto me envía a una actividad nueva siempre desde el IntentService, entonces se inicia una actividad nueva pero la anterior no la puedo finalizar porque no puedo hacer un finish() desde el IntentService.

Comment: Una idea que te doy sería usar `broadcast`, en el intentService no abras la activity, le envias un `broadcast` diciendole que abra la nueva y cierre esa. Si te interesa puedo crear una respuesta.

Comment: Hola, es que estoy usando este tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/  
Revisa la clase HttpService, en la funcion verifyOtp, se inicia una actividad nueva pero no sale como cerrarla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por tu respuesta, pude resolver mi problema cambiando las 3 lineas de codigo del Intent por estas:

```
Intent intent = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

De esta forma la aplicacion se reinicia y puede verificarse, que es el problema que tenia con ese tutorial:
https://www.androidhive.info/2015/08/android-adding-sms-verification-like-whatsapp-part-2/

Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría, sin saber exactamente como funciona ese código, prueba y verás si es lo que necesitas o no.

No iniciaría la activity en `IntentService`, haría lo siguiente:

Donde ahora inicias la activity, llamaría un `broadcast`

```
Intent intent = new Intent("cerrarActivity");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Y luego en la activity que quieres cerrar:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // aqui abres la nueva activity y cierras la actual
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter("cerrarActivity")); // register broadcast

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver); // unregister broadcast
    }
```